# Combine tables of aggregated values with summarised variables from 'parent' data set

Tags: r

I have a data set along these lines:

```
df<-data.frame(sp=c(100, 100, 100, 101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102),
type=c("C","C","C","H","H","H","C","C","C"),
country=c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
vals=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
)
```

I want to aggregate df$vals and bring the other variables through as well

At the moment I'm doing it like this:

```
multi.func<- function(x){
c(
n = length(x),
min = min(x, na.rm=TRUE),
max = max(x, na.rm=TRUE),
mean = mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)
)}

aggVals<-as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, by(df$vals, df$sp, FUN=multi.func, simplify=TRUE)))
aggVals$sp<-row.names(aggVals)

aggDescrip<-aggregate(cbind(as.character(type), as.character(country)) ~ sp, data=df, FUN=unique)

result<-merge(aggDescrip,aggVals)
```

This works well enough but I wondered if there's an easier way.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you should look into the `data.table` package.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df, key="sp")
DT[, list(type = unique(as.character(type)), 
          country = unique(as.character(country)), 
          n = .N, min = min(vals), max = max(vals), 
          mean = mean(vals)), by=key(DT)]
#     sp type country n min max mean
# 1: 100    C       A 3   1   3    2
# 2: 101    H       B 3   4   6    5
# 3: 102    C       C 3   7   9    8
```

---

If you want to stick with base R, here is another approach that might be of use (though `aggregate` is probably more common):

```
unique(within(df, {
    mean <- ave(vals, sp, FUN=mean)
    max <- ave(vals, sp, FUN=max)
    min <- ave(vals, sp, FUN=min)
    n <- ave(vals, sp, FUN=length)
    rm(vals)
}))
#    sp type country n min max mean
# 1 100    C       A 3   1   3    2
# 4 101    H       B 3   4   6    5
# 7 102    C       C 3   7   9    8
```

---

#### Update: A variation on your initial attempt

I would suggest sticking with `data.table` if possible, because the resulting code is easy to follow and the process of aggregation is quick.

However, with a little bit of modification, you can have (yet another) base R approach that is somewhat more direct.

First, modify your function so that instead of using `c()`, use `data.frame`. Also, add an argument that specifies which column needs to be aggregated.

```
multi.func <- function(x, value_column) {
    data.frame(
        n = length(x[[value_column]]),
        min = min(x[[value_column]], na.rm=TRUE),
        max = max(x[[value_column]], na.rm=TRUE),
        mean = mean(x[[value_column]], na.rm=TRUE))
}
```

Second, use `lapply` on your dataset, `split` up by your grouping variable, `merge` the output with your original dataset, and return the `unique` values.

```
unique(merge(df[-4], 
             do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$sp), 
                                   multi.func, value_column = "vals")),
             by.x = "sp", by.y = "row.names"))
```

Comment: Thanks for both answers.  I'll use the ave method for now as I have to share code with people who only use base R.  I spotted data.table on the #rstats twitter feed last week - been meaning to give it a try as it looks fantastic.

Comment: @EdG, well, now there are three answers ;)   The `data.table` package is *awesome* for a lot of stuff, quick aggregation by groups just being one of them.

Comment: Third answer is really helpful - thanks again. I've gone with that one as I've got ore than one set of values to aggregate.  Will definitely check data.frame too

Answer (score 2):

Using just `aggregate`:

```
result <- aggregate(vals ~ type + sp + country, df, 
    function(x) c(length(x), min(x), max(x), mean(x))
)

result
  type  sp country vals.1 vals.2 vals.3 vals.4
1    C 100       A      3      1      3      2
2    H 101       B      3      4      6      5
3    C 102       C      3      7      9      8

colnames(result)
[1] "type"    "sp"      "country" "vals"
```

---

The above seems to create a weird "multi-value" column. But `summaryBy` from the `doBy` package is similar to `aggregate` but will allow an output with multiple columns:

```
library(doBy)
result <- summaryBy(vals ~ type + sp + country, df, 
    FUN=function(x) c(n=length(x), min=min(x), max=max(x), mean=mean(x))
)

result
  type  sp country vals.n vals.min vals.max vals.mean
1    C 100       A      3        1        3         2
2    C 102       C      3        7        9         8
3    H 101       B      3        4        6         5

colnames(result)
[1] "type"      "sp"        "country"   "vals.n"    "vals.min"  "vals.max" 
[7] "vals.mean"
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for your reply. When I run this code I get four variables and the last one ($vals) seems to have n, min, max and mean stacked on top of each other. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: @EdG yes that's supposed to happen but I didn't realise they were all part of one column. Try the other answer here or look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065904/r-aggregate-with-multiple-arguments-in-function). Both suggest using `data.table` as an alternative.

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful.  Must learn more about doBy!